# Navigation on Website Positioned Incorrectly

Tags: html, css

I'm currently converting my portfolio mock up into html/css and I've come across something that has confused me.

http://www.mozazdesign.co.cc/

As you can see, the navigation text is positioned in the wrong place; I want it to be inline with the markers. I've looked through the code loads and looked at other websites but can't figure out why it's not working..

This is the exact code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>MozazDesign Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">

        </div><!--end logo-->

        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="main_nav">
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
            </ul><!--end main nav-->
        </div><!--end nav-->
    </div><!--end header-->



</body>

body {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
background:url('Images/background.png');
font-family: century gothic;
}

#nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}

#container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
}

#logo {
background:url('Images/Logo.png');
height: 340px;
width: 524px;
float: left;
margin-left: 0px;  <!--check-->
}

#nav {
background:url('Images/Nav_Container.png');
width: 427px;
height: 33px;
float: right;
margin-top: 100px;

}

#main_nav li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
font-family: century gothic;
font-size: 18px;
color: white;
margin-right: 17px;
}
```

Any ideas why it isn't positioned correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new CSS class:

```
#main_nav
{
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```

Adjust the top value until it looks correct.

The relative position says 'position this element where it naturally occurs' and then you can use '`Top`' and '`Left`' values (positive values to move it down and right, negative to move it up or left) to modify it's position from it's relative position.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if he changes the `margin` (from `margin: 1em 0;` to something like: `margin: 0 0 0 1em;`) the `#main_nav` element gets moved up naturally. (Or **isn't moved down** by `1em`)

Comment: Thanks a lot!Didn't think of styling the main_nav. For some reason it added padding even tho I set padding to 0px in the body styling? Oh well, thanks for your help! :D